# Model-based Calibration Toolbox in Matlab 2011a 64

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab 2011a, 64bit and looking for Model-based Calibration toolbox but I couldn't find.

In the last version (2009) I just typed in the command line: "mbcmodel" and I got the toolbox. But in this version, I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not have the product installed with your new version. Type `ver` at the MATLAB command line to see which products you have installed. If you don't see Model Based Calibration Toolbox, that would be the issue.

Comment: Here is my MATLAB Version: 7.12.0.635 (R2011a)

But I don't see the Model-based Calibration toolbox :(
What can I do to get it? 
I want to use it to design my experiments

Comment: When you type `ver`, you should see a list of all the products you have installed, including MATLAB itself and any toolboxes, such as Statistics, Optimization, or Model Based Calibration Toolboxes. If you don't see Model Based Calibration Toolbox, you don't have the product, and you need to either find someone who does have it, or contact MathWorks to buy it.